# What is the best way to bind the same type twice (e.g. a wrapper) for dependency injection in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Say I have a service type `Service` that has a number of different implementations, `ServiceImplX` and `ServiceImplY`. I also have a caching layer, `CachedService`, that implements `Service` and wraps some basic implementation of `Service` to access the data.

What I want is to be able to bind one of `ServiceImplX` and `ServiceImplY` as the basic implementation to be injected into `CachedService`, while `CachedService` itself should be bound to `Service` to be injected into actual clients of this service.

I would like to avoid naming annotations to solve this since that seems fragile. Is there any safer way of achieving this?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a proper binding annotation:

```
@RetentionPolicy(RUNTIME)
@BindingAnnotation
@interface ServiceBinding {}
```

This is a lot more robust than an `@Named` binding annotation because:

- It's a symbol, just like a class name or variable, so you can easily find references to it in your code; the name in an `@Named` annotation can be constructed at runtime, so it is much harder to find.
- You can control the accessibility of a binding annotation via `public`/`private` etc modifiers, so you can control where the annotation is configured and referenced. The strings of `@Named` annotations are in a global scope.